# Not getting published message from MQTT broker in Paho client

Tags: mqtt, paho, moquette

I have setup a Moquette MQTT broker and connected it with eclipse Paho client (I will call this `paho1`). Subscribing to `in/#` topic.

I created another Paho client (I will call this `paho2`), with a different client id of course, and published it to the broker with `in/device` topic.

At first, the packet was delivered successfully. However, when I disconnect `paho2` and reconnect to the broker and send the same packet, it is not delivered to `paho1`.

I wonder why this is happening. My settings for the Paho client is `qos = 0` (I tried 1 and 2 as well).

```
MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
connOpts.setCleanSession(false);
```

I was looking at the log of broker and it comes as follows. When successful, my protocol version is printed to the log.

[image: when Succeeded]

[image: Failed]

Comment: Do you definitely mean `in/*` not `in/#`?

Comment: @ralight I've changed to in/# I figured out that was wrong. Still, I ain't getting the message from the broker.. does MQTT broker filters the same packet?

Comment: I can see that broker is republishing the message to my paho2. however, the callback is not responding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying to replicate the problem with different tools. With the broker running, run a subscribing client:

```
mosquitto_sub -h <hostname> -t in/# -v
```

Then separately do the publishing:

```
mosquitto_pub -h <hostname> -t in/device -m message
```

This should return very quickly and your mosquitto_sub instance should print `in/device message`. Repeat the publish and you should see the same thing.

If you do not see a repeated message, there is a problem with the broker. If would then try using e.g. mosquitto as the broker and repeating with your code.

If you do see the repeated message using mosquitto_pub/sub, your code is somehow at fault. You can carry on trying different permutations until you have a better idea where the problem lies - i.e. use mosquitto_pub+your sub, mosquitto_sub+your pub.

Comment: I tried this with spy-mqtt. seems like other client is receiving the messages correctly... seems like problem with my client then.. is it suggested to use publish client and subscribe client separately?

Comment: There's no need to have separate pub/sub clients. But isn't that what you're doing anyway with paho1 and paho2? Or are they two instances of a client within one program?

Comment: I found where the problem is occurring. I was calling publish or subscribe method from the callback method. This cause the client to be stuck for some reason. So I created another client to publish. Also I subscribed after the callback was handled. Now it is working well.